# Mysql - latin1 (with latin2 content) to utf8

Tags: mysql, encoding

I have a database (ubbthreads) encoded in latin1 with content from latin2 (polish characters).

Since latin2 is compatible with latin1 it looks fine on the website, however I cannot convert it in any way to utf8 (want to import the data to nodebb).

It also doesn't render characters correctly in console mysql as well as in mysql workbench.

I tried numerous of ways to do the conversion and all of this failed.

My last try was to convert mysqldump file first from latin1 to latin2, and I planned to do next conversion from latin2 tu utf8.

However, iconv breaks in first polish character attempt with 
`illegal input sequence at position 11392`

I need some tips how to do it in a correct way.

Comment: Just for the record. I didn't have to use this in the end. Nodebb importer (also the reason to do this procedure) handles latin2 to ut8 converting on post-import phase with custom script just fine.

However, I marked Alex'es answer as correct one, since this is one and probably only way to do it using mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
INSERT INTO original_new()
SELECT CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(`field` USING latin2) AS BINARY) USING utf8) 
FROM original
```

Comment: Thank you, however that would be my last resort since it will require lots of work to create a script that will do the jobs.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you state two *independent* things:

- The encoding of the bytes in the client, and
- The encoding in the column in the table.

That is, you *can* have one of them be utf8 and the other be latin2.  This is *without* any use of `CONVERT()`, etc.

Since it is unclear what settings you have where, I can't be more specific.